# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSomething() on null in phtml ViewModel magento2

Tags: magento2, viewmodel

I have created a ViewModel, when I am calling it in the phtml it giving me the below error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSomething() on null in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml:16 Stack trace: #0

here is my catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block name="product.info.upsell.customviewmodel"
                   class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Noshad\VMpractice\ViewModel\PreparePostData</argument>
                    </arguments>
            </block>
```

here is my ViewModel class

```
<?php

namespace Noshad\VMpractice\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;


class PreparePostData implements ArgumentInterface
{


    public function getSomething()
    {
        echo 'find me';
    }

}
```

here are my items.phtml code

```
/* @var Noshad\VMpractice\ViewModel\PreparePostData $viewModel */

$viewModel =  $block->getData('view_model');

echo $viewModel->getSomething();
```

whenever I load the product detail page I gets the below error:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSomething() on null in** /var/www/html/practice234/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml:16 Stack trace: #0

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code :-

**`ViewModel/Custom.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Mage\Mohit\ViewModel;

class Custom implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{

    public function __construct(
       
    ) {
    }

    public function getSomething() {
        return "Hello Magento Stackexchange";
    }
}
```

**`items.phtml`**

```
<?php

$viewModel = $block->getData('view_model');
echo $viewModel->getSomething();
```

**`catalog_product_view.xml`**

```
<block name="product.info.upsell.customviewmodel"
                   class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   template="Mag_Mohit::items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Mage\Mohit\ViewModel\Custom</argument>
                    </arguments>
            </block>
```

After below commmands run :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the value is working if I place the items.phtml file in the same module if I give the reference of magento_catalog items.phtml then it throws the same error, I think the view model will work in the same module where I have created it. Thanks

Comment: pls accept answer

Comment: done, please like my question also

Comment: Please accept answer if helped my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `\` in your xml before your class